# Analytic, never zero on domain D graph and its local max. min

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, definition

If $f$ is analytic and never zero on domain D, then $|f(z)|$ has no local minimum or maximum.

Now,

If I use the fact that $|f(z)|\leq$ max $|f(z+re^{it})|$ ($0\leq t\leq 2\pi$), then I can show that $|f|$ has no strict local maximum within its domain of analyticity by contradiction.

My question is, how do I use this to show that $|f(z)|$ has no local minimum?

Also, one conceptual question from my textbook is that, what does it mean when they say that $|f(z)|\leq$ max $|f(z+re^{it})|$ ($0\leq t\leq 2\pi$) true for "sufficiently" small $r$?

Comment: If $f$ has no zero in $D$, then $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is analytic in $D$...

Comment: @fgp: ok, so I can consider $|1/f(c)|>|1/f(z) \forall z\in D|$ where c is the local min, and that will make a contradiction with the max, right?

Comment: Yes. Any maximum of $|f|$ is a minimum of $|1/f| = 1/|f|$ and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the conceptual question, we see that for $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and $r$ fixed, then $z+re^{it}$, is a circle radius $r$ about $z$, so for sufficiently small $r$ gives us a **local** condition.